# anyone can guide me on how to actually using neovim command

Tags: neovim

I am trying to use the same way in vim for set `signcolumn=number` however seems neovim says it is replaced by `sign define` and followed by `numhl` everyone talking to use it instead but seems nobody gives the step on how to use it. the same way when I am looking for how to highlight the number only but not the line like in vim set `cursorlineopt=number` there is special command to used to replace the vim command but I don't know how to actually use it.

this is the link I am referring to [github on how to user signcolumn on neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/11667#issuecomment-570698648)

so anyone could guide me on how to actually use it, thank you very much for your care.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part isn't working? You'll find this site is not very good to explain how something works (as in a blog post, or the actual documentation for Vim and NeoVim), but it's great for helping you debug a specific issue you're having. But your question right now is very general and doesn't describe a specific issue... You'll get more useful answers if you update your question with an example of what you have tried and what about it didn't work.

Comment: I tried those command in my `init.vim` but doesn't work. but  I got the answer anyway as the guy on reddit and below replies it seems neovim is not support this functionalities yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to use `signcolumn=number` in the next release. The last release of neovim was on August 7, and [the PR adding it to neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/12621) was only merged on August 10. (Or you can try [a nightly build](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Installing-Neovim#macos--os-x).)

Comment: alright thank you, I never thought of that one and always curious why neovim does not support that I thought it has covered all the vim functionalities. thank you